# How to bind and unbind events jquery: carousel script modification

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I have a jQuery Carousel script and I want to modify it's behavior slightly. Here is the script and test case in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4vHf/1/ . Below is the JS code.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.easyPaginate = function(options){

        var defaults = {                
            step: 4,
            delay: 100,
            numeric: true,
            nextprev: true,
            auto:false,
            pause:4000,
            clickstop:true,
            controls: 'pagination',
            current: 'current' 
        }; 

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 
        var step = options.step;
        var lower, upper;
        var children = $(this).children();
        var count = children.length;
        var obj, next, prev;        
        var page = 1;
        var timeout;
        var clicked = false;

        function show(){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            lower = ((page-1) * step);
            upper = lower+step;
            $(children).each(function(i){
                var child = $(this);
                child.hide();
                if(i>=lower && i<upper){ setTimeout(function(){ child.fadeIn('fast') }, ( i-( Math.floor(i/step) * step) )*options.delay ); }
                if(options.nextprev){
                    if(upper >= count) { next.fadeOut('fast'); } else { next.fadeIn('fast'); };
                    if(lower >= 1) { prev.fadeIn('fast'); } else { prev.fadeOut('fast'); };
                };
            }); 
            $('li','#'+ options.controls).removeClass(options.current);
            $('li[data-index="'+page+'"]','#'+ options.controls).addClass(options.current);

            if(options.auto){
                if(options.clickstop && clicked){}else{ timeout = setTimeout(auto,options.pause); };
            };
        };

        function auto(){
            if(upper <= count){ page++; show(); }           
        };

        this.each(function(){ 

            obj = this;

            if(count>step){

                var pages = Math.floor(count/step);
                if((count/step) > pages) pages++;

                var ol = $('<ol id="'+ options.controls +'"></ol>').insertAfter(obj);

                if(options.nextprev){
                    prev = $('<li class="prev">Previous</li>')
                        .hide()
                        .appendTo(ol)
                        .click(function(){
                            clicked = true;
                            page--;
                            show();
                        });
                };

                if(options.numeric){
                    for(var i=1;i<=pages;i++){
                    $('<li data-index="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</li>')
                        .appendTo(ol)
                        .click(function(){  
                            clicked = true;
                            page = $(this).attr('data-index');
                            show();
                        });                 
                    };              
                };

                if(options.nextprev){
                    next = $('<li class="next">Next</li>')
                        .hide()
                        .appendTo(ol)
                        .click(function(){
                            clicked = true;         
                            page++;
                            show();
                        });
                };

                show();
            };
        }); 

    };  

})(jQuery);
```

My goal is to make the `class="prev"` and `class="next"` buttons always visible. I removed the `hide();` methods from the code, but I also need to remove the click event handlers because otherwise I can still click on the buttons even when I'm on the last or first pages accordingly - and that's here things get messed up. I have to bind and unbind the click events but don't know how to do it properly. So here is my modified version:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.easyPaginate = function(options){

    var defaults = {                
        step: 4,
        delay: 100,
        numeric: true,
        nextprev: true,
        auto:false,
        pause:4000,
        clickstop:true,
        controls: 'pagination',
        current: 'current' 
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 
    var step = options.step;
    var lower, upper;
    var children = $(this).children();
    var count = children.length;
    var obj, next, prev;        
    var page = 1;
    var timeout;
    var clicked = false;

    function show(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        lower = ((page-1) * step);
        upper = lower+step;
        $(children).each(function(i){
            var child = $(this);
            child.hide();
            if(i>=lower && i<upper){ setTimeout(function(){ child.fadeIn('fast') }, ( i-( Math.floor(i/step) * step) )*options.delay ); }
            if(options.nextprev){
                if(upper >= count) { next.fadeOut('fast'); } else { next.fadeIn('fast'); };
                if(lower >= 1) { prev.fadeIn('fast'); } else { prev.fadeOut('fast'); };
            };
        }); 
        $('li','#'+ options.controls).removeClass(options.current);
        $('li[data-index="'+page+'"]','#'+ options.controls).addClass(options.current);

        if(options.auto){
            if(options.clickstop && clicked){}else{ timeout = setTimeout(auto,options.pause); };
        };
    };

    function auto(){
        if(upper <= count){ page++; show(); }           
    };

    this.each(function(){ 

        obj = this;

        if(count>step){

            var pages = Math.floor(count/step);
            if((count/step) > pages) pages++;

            var ol = $('<ol id="'+ options.controls +'"></ol>').insertAfter(obj);

            if(options.nextprev){
                prev = $('<li class="prev">Previous</li>')
                    .appendTo(ol)
                    .bind('click', function() {
                        clicked = true;
                        page--;
                        show();
                    });
            };

            if(options.numeric){
                for(var i=1;i<=pages;i++){
                $('<li data-index="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</li>')
                    .appendTo(ol)
                    .click(function(){  
                        clicked = true;
                        page = $(this).attr('data-index');
                        show();
                    });                 
                };              
            };

            if(options.nextprev){
                next = $('<li class="next">Next</li>')
                    .appendTo(ol)
                    .bind('click', function() {
                        clicked = true;         
                        page++;
                        show();
                    });
            };

            show();
        };
    }); 

};  

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just checking inside your event handlers if the user has reached the bounds of the pages?

```
        if(options.nextprev){
            prev = $('<li class="prev">Previous</li>')
                .appendTo(ol)
                .bind('click', function() {

                    //check to see if there are any more pages in the negative direction
                    if (page > 0) {
                        clicked = true;
                        page--;
                        show();
                    }
                });
        }

        if(options.nextprev){
            next = $('<li class="next">Next</li>')
                .appendTo(ol)
                .bind('click', function() {

                    //check to see if there are any pages in the positive direction
                    if ((page + 1) < count) {
                        clicked = true;         
                        page++;
                        show();
                    }
                });
        }
```

### Update

If you want the previous and next buttons to never dissapear then you need to remove the code in the `show()` function that fades the elements in and out. That section of code is this:

```
        if(options.nextprev){
            if(upper >= count) { next.fadeOut('fast'); } else { next.fadeIn('fast'); };
            if(lower >= 1) { prev.fadeIn('fast'); } else { prev.fadeOut('fast'); };
        };
```

A simple fix is to just comment this section-out, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A4vHf/18/

Comment: seems like a nice workaround, I will set it up in jsfiddle with an example to see how and if it works..

Comment: nop, sorry, doesn't work, http://jsfiddle.net/A4vHf/3/ the buttons still disappear (no idea why!)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos You need to remove any code that changes the display of the previous and next buttons. I **updated** my answer with this change: http://jsfiddle.net/A4vHf/18/

Comment: if you click previous when in page 1 or next when in last page, all the <li>'s get set to display:none; .. Would it be possible to move the if before the binding of the click event? Or somehow unbind the event completely when we reached the end of the pages?

Comment: I actually added an alert(pages); and it seems pages is always 7.. http://jsfiddle.net/A4vHf/22/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A4vHf/24/. The `if` statement inside the event handler for the previous button needs to check if `page > 1` instead of `page > 0` since you are not starting at page zero, you're starting at page one. The `if` statement inside the event handler for the next button needs to check to see if the current `page` is less than half the total pages since you are showing two pages at once. See the updated JSFiddle I posted in this comment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Jasper. I actually would try to make this automatic (so that if I choose to display 4 slides instead of 2 it works) (I guess I can use the step variable for that..). Answer accepted.